# Error when creating dataset with h5py python

Tags: python, dataset, h5py

I'm trying to run code from here in Google Colab [code I run](https://github.com/jadevaibhav/Signature-verification-using-deep-learning/blob/master/final_code.ipynb)

But on second line of

```
hf = h5py.File('data_1.h5', 'w')

hf.create_dataset('dataset_1', data=x)
```

I get following error:

```
    116         else:
    117             dtype = numpy.dtype(dtype)
    --> 118         tid = h5t.py_create(dtype, logical=1)    
    119     
    120     # Legacy
    h5py/h5t.pyx in h5py.h5t.py_create()
    h5py/h5t.pyx in h5py.h5t.py_create()
    h5py/h5t.pyx in h5py.h5t.py_create()

    TypeError: Object dtype dtype('O') has no native HDF5 equivalent
```

Why does it appear? What's the root cause? Any ideas on how to fix it?

What I see in x is

```
    [[array([[[255., 255., 255.],
            [255., 255., 255.],
            [255., 255., 255.],
            ...,
            [255., 255., 255.],
            [255., 255., 255.],
            [255., 255., 255.]],
    
           [[255., 255., 255.],
            [255., 255., 255.],
            [255., 255., 255.],
            .......
```

Comment: I don't think your `x` is a proper numeric array.  If it's a list, look at `np.array(x)`.  What is the `dtype`?  the shape?

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `neural-network` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Thank you for the note! I'll keep in mind

Answer (score 0):

The fix for code is to keep the x like this:

```
hf.create_dataset('dataset_1', (len(x),), dtype=dt)
hf['dataset_1'][...] = x
```